# Windows Service is not starting when I manually stopped and shutdown system and turn on

Tags: c#, windows-services

Currently I'm facing an issue as described below

I have bunch of background services which will register to windows services with following configuration.

General Tab Info

```
Startup Type: Automatic (Delayed Start)
```

Recovery Tab Info

```
First failure: Restart the Service

Second failure: Restart the Service

Subsequent failure: Restart the Service
```

So, with the above configuration my service is working fine, and I have a use case where I will stop the services (manually and programmatically) for a reason.

Problem Statement as below

```
When I manually stop the service and shutdown the system and waited for couple of minutes then turn on the system again waited for 15 min none of the service is started.
```

I've spent lot of time to figured out but no luck so far, looking forward for solution.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I set the service type with **Automatic-Delay** and the regedit value of **ServicesPipeTimeout** default **(30000 mSec)** and the custom one **60000 mSec**, they did not work as expected.

The reason for the automatic-delay start is due to the service loading time for some large data processing—one of the scenarios I have.

PS: When I manually stop and shut down and turn on, service is not starting.

Solution: Increase the ServicesPipeTimeout value to 180000 mSec and the Service type is changed to Automatic.

Here is where the magic happened to me. All the services started working as expected.

Automatic-Delay start has some technical limitations—I'm not sure what the limitations were and there is no specific document.

Solution I tried in the following OS: **Windows 10 Pro and Windows Server 2019**